# Problems with MathJax rendering

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I'm trying to use MathJax in my HTML and PHP files.
I'm using a local version of polyfill and the MathJax  from the cdn:

```
<script src="js/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

Furthermore I use the following configuration

```
<script>
   window.MathJax = {
      tex: {
         tags: "all",
         inlineMath: [
            ['$', '$'],
            ["\\(", "\\)"]
         ],
      },
   }; 
</script>
```

The HTML Code is the following, containing some math

```
<ul>
    <li>$x$ Lorem Ipsum ....</li>
    <li>$y$ Lorem Ipsum ....</li>
</ul>
```

Now I have the problem, that sometimes (often the first time) I'm loading the page MathJax does not render. When I'm refreshing, in 90% of the cases everything is fine, sometimes I have to refresh again.
How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!